# Travis-CI does not publish doxygen file-level documentation

Tags: github, travis-ci, doxygen, github-pages

I have a [project](https://github.com/Jon-Burr/RDFAnalysis) for which I'm building the doxygen documentation in a CI job and [publishing using github-pages](https://jon-burr.github.io/RDFAnalysis/).

However, I'm running into an issue where the documentation for files (i.e. generated with [doxygen's @file command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdfile) ) does not get uploaded - the links exist and the files exist in the gh-pages branch but clicking on any link leads to a 404 error. For example [this](https://jon-burr.github.io/RDFAnalysis/_cutflow_detail_8h.html) should lead to [this](https://github.com/Jon-Burr/RDFAnalysis/blob/gh-pages/_cutflow_detail_8h.html) file but the link is dead.

As far as I can tell, this is because Jekyll is ignoring any file whose name begins with an underscore, and this is the output pattern that doxygen uses with (as far as I can tell) no way to change that. It looks like to fix this you need to tell Jekyll to include these files but this has not worked for me so far.

I have tried

- [Adding a _config.yml file to the master branch to include `_*.html` files](https://github.com/Jon-Burr/RDFAnalysis/commit/d1e07188fe1172fbf5c7516b3da4e9bd98d99bdd)
- [Modifying that file to include `_`](https://github.com/Jon-Burr/RDFAnalysis/commit/a2916a579c22cc8d33219df4f1bdfd6facc39b29)
- [Swapping that file for a `.nojekyll` file](https://github.com/Jon-Burr/RDFAnalysis/commit/b24ca72d86a3bfaa9ce7e941ab4402b81a4ee4d2)
- [Creating a .nojekyll file as part of the build](https://github.com/Jon-Burr/RDFAnalysis/commit/eaeebb8e4234a4123b7894c9262c62a908407c62)
- Creating a _config.yml file in the gh-pages branch (this one has no link because travis completely overrides it :P )

Any of these files I create on the master branch seems to be ignored in the gh-pages branch and anything I create on the gh-pages branch is (predictably) overwritten by travis.

How can I get these files published to the webpage?

Comment: A real example would be useful as well as the used doxygen version. Furthermore does everything build properly? or is it just an upload part that is not working or ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a real example - you want something more than the links to the github project and documentation page?

Everything builds correctly - for example the [linked html file on the gh-pages branch](https://github.com/Jon-Burr/RDFAnalysis/blob/gh-pages/_cutflow_detail_8h.html) or the [published documentation for one of the classes](https://jon-burr.github.io/RDFAnalysis/class_r_d_f_analysis_1_1_cutflow_detail.html)

Comment: It looks like it is build with a very old version of doxygen (1.8.6, from December 2013) whilst the current version is 1.8.15. You could have a look at the configuration setting `CASE_SENSE_NAMES`, maybe this can help you to overcome problems with the `_` -names.

Comment: Hi - sorry, I forgot to answer your question about the doxygen version - I was just using whichever one the CI grabbed by default.

CASE_SENSE_NAMES works! If you want to repeat it in an answer so I can accept it that would be great.

Comment: I do advise not to use the default (1.8.6) version but use a newer version of doxygen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doxygen decides, as default, how to create output filenames based on the OS used. This results a.o. in a way that on case insensitive systems there are always unique names (e.g by replacing an upper case character with an underscore followed by the corresponding  lowercase character (underscores are replaced by double underscores).
To steer this the configuration parameter `CASE_SENSE_NAMES` can be used.

From the the documentation (1.8.15):

> CASE_SENSE_NAMES If the CASE_SENSE_NAMES tag is set to NO then doxygen
>   will only generate file names in lower-case letters. If set to YES,
>   upper-case letters are also allowed. This is useful if you have
>   classes or files whose names only differ in case and if your file
>   system supports case sensitive file names.
>
> Windows and Mac users are advised to set this option to NO.
>
> The default value is: system dependent.